# Unity buttons that place objects

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm not sure how to place objects in unity using buttons. I'm making a small strategy game for class that places buildings in the game, and then those buildings do something. I haven't been able to find any good tutorials for getting the buttons to place things. Any help?

Comment: Do you mean to ask "How to display a building on the GUI when users press a button" ?

Comment: Not necessarily. I need it to place an new object in the world when a user presses a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it:

1. Create prefabs for your GameObjects so you can grab them in real-time
2. Add a button script for your insert button
   something like this:

   ```
    public void createObj(){
        // Instantiate at position (0, 0, 0) and zero rotation.
        Instantiate(myPrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
   ```

   }
3. Add this script to your button.